# Android Native Store Link Not Working In Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Running:

`window.open("market://details?id=com.itemtopia.app", "_system", "location=yes");`

Throws:

net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
(market://details?id=com.itemtopia.app)

With config.xml settings

`<access launch-external="yes" origin="market:*" />
<allow-navigation href="market://*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />`

Cordova version: 7.1.0

Android: 6.0.1

Device: Nexus 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When both `access` and `allow-navigation` are set allow navigation takes priority and tries to navigate the web view to "market://details?id=com.itemtopia.app".

#### Solution

Remove `<allow-navigation href="market://*" />` from config.xml.